# curl call with parameters into variable doesn't work

Tags: shell, curl

I'm working with installr API.
I'm trying to do the following curl request via a script :

```
curl -H "X-InstallrAppToken: mytoken"  https://www.installrapp.com/apps.json/ \
  -F 'qqfile=@'$APKPATH \
  -F 'releaseNotes=These are my release notes' \
  -F 'notify=true'
```

and it works perfectly.
However, when I try to get my release notes from a file with a variable like this :

```
RELEASENOTES=`cat "release_notes/test.md"`
curl -H "X-InstallrAppToken: mytoken"  https://www.installrapp.com/apps.json/ \
  -F 'qqfile=@'$APKPATH \
  -F 'releaseNotes='$RELEASENOTES \
  -F 'notify=true' > /dev/null
```

it doesn't work at all, only the first word is sent. For the others, I have the error Could not resolve host: xxx.

I did a `echo` on these two curl request and the exact same thing is printed.
is that the `cat`command which return a specific format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably an issue with the quotes and spaces. You can use double-quotes around a variable to allow variable expansion in the shell.

```
RELEASENOTES=$(cat "release_notes/test.md")
curl -H "X-InstallrAppToken: mytoken"  https://www.installrapp.com/apps.json/ \
  -F "qqfile=@${APKPATH}" \
  -F "releaseNotes=${RELEASENOTES}" \
  -F 'notify=true' > /dev/null
```